# Client for processing messages from TCP/IP

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone propose good design idea for implementing "Client for processing messages from TCP/IP".Messages are xml and are of three types(A,B,C). Processing involves parsing of xml and saving result in file storage.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) ?